# Using Cassandra for user registration

Tags: node.js, mongodb, cassandra

I am using Cassandra for a social app I am working on. I really like all Cassandra has to offer. I want to know if it is okay to store username and password in Cassandra itself or should I use a second database (mongodb) for storing username and password. Will eventual consistency cause problems when a user resets password or changes email. I am using email as primary key to look up user data. I am writing the backend in JavaScript in node.js.

Let me explain what i am trying to do. I want to add a password reset and a lock out feature after lets say 5 wrong password tries. The problem is if the user tries to login before the third servers updates and what happens if the password is compared to the outdated data on the third server? Wouldn't the user get locked out. Is the best course of action to store the username and password in a separate database such as mongodb? Or is their another way to solve this issue.

Comment: Thank you pherris, I like the benefits Cassandra offers via eventual consistency. I want to keep the database at eventual consistency. That is the reason for the post. Let me explain what i am trying to do. I want to add a password reset and a lock out feature after lets say 5 wrong password tries. The problem is if the user tries to login before the third servers updates and what happens if the password is compared to the outdated data on the third server? Wouldn't the user get locked out. I though may be i can solve the problem by storing just the login data in mongoDB. Does that sound good?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store username/pwd in Cassandra - their basic data modeling page has a relevant example that may help your thinking: http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/basic-rules-of-cassandra-data-modeling.

Eventual consistency could be an issue if you don't pay attention to how you read and write data (and your reads/writes happen near each other). It is possible to tune the cluster to behave like a 'normal' store (e.g. once I write the data, subsequent reads will get the last written value); however, the configuration below reduces some of the great things Cassandra brings to the table.

### Data Consistency

You can configure a [data consistency](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/dml/dml_config_consistency_c.html) of `ALL` for your **writes** - meaning that you ensure that all nodes are up to date before your write completes. No eventual consistency issues on the writes.

> A write must be written to the commit log and memtable on all replica nodes in the cluster for that partition key.

However, this write takes longer and requires that enough nodes are up and available for you to get the guarantees you are asking for.

You can also specify **read** consistency of `ALL` which means:

> Returns the record after all replicas have responded. The read operation will fail if a replica does not respond.

In this case, if you are writing data to three nodes and one of them is unable to respond your read will fail because Cassandra cannot provide the requested guarantee of consistency.

I should point out that these are the most strict configurations you can use and there are others that may work for your situation. The point I am trying to make is: as you ask Cassandra to behave like a more traditional store, you trade off some of the aspects of the cluster that are really appealing.

You need to consider the anticipated characteristics of your system (read volume, write volume, importance of those two being in sync etc) when making this decision. IMOP while you probably *could* use Cassandra for this type of data, unless you are dealing with a huge volume of users, it wouldn't be my first choice.